# Implement nonce in REST app DELETE method

Tags: php, rest, nonce

With methods POST GET and PUT I can send the nonce value to the server along with the rest of the client request data, but DELETE method it's not supposed to carry any parameters, just the name of the resource.

I'm thinking of using If-Match header.

Would that be right?

(I know the nonce is supposed to be part of some auth scheme, like OAuth or HTTP Digest access authentication, but right now I'm not going full REST and prefer to use session authentication. Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong and should reconsider this?)

Comment: What are you using the nonce for?

Comment: send it as a get parameter, or as a header, it doesn't matter as long as it reaches the destination. Be aware that some proxy will strip your custom headers. Also, the If-Match header has other usage, not for your case.

Comment: I use nonce to avoid processing the same request more than once.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. DELETE operations should be idempotent - i.e. processing them multiple times should leave the system in the same state as if they were just called once.

Comment: Well I am processing DELETE just that way, so I guess using nonce is in fact a little bit redundant, nevertheless I want to know if I already received the request before processing it and throw a "duplicate request" instead of a "resource not found" (they could both be an error 400 and it won't be much of a difference, or 400 vs 404, but still...). Is that ok? ("RESTing" for the first time here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct (and only) place for authentication data, such as a custom nonce value, is in the **request headers.**

1. You can't send it as part of the URL (including query param) because that would alter the resource you were trying to delete. Query parameters are part of the resource identifier, and anyone who tells you otherwise is lying.
2. You can't send it in the body because the delete method has no request body.

Comment: but what about clients behind a proxy? Will the header used as a custom nonce (i.e. If-Match) pass trough and reach my server? Is there any specific standard header I should use or should I make my own?

Comment: I finally went on and defined a custom "X-Myapp-Nonce" header. I tried trough a couple of proxies and everything went fine, so I guess I'll stick with that.

Comment: @elcodedocle Proxies should not modify custom headers they know nothing about. That would break much of the internet if they did (e.g. the upgrade from HTTP 1.0 to HTTP 1.1 would not have been possible).